# How do we show that integer addition, multiplication and the less-than sign are well-defined in Van der Waerden?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Van der Waerden's *Algebra I*, the integers are defined prior to the discussion on equivalence relationships and partitions.

He begins by introducing the natural numbers ($1, 2, \ldots{}$) in a semi-formal way, listing the Peano axioms and then giving the usual inductive definitions for addition and multiplication, together with the regular properties (associativity, commutativity and distributivity, as well as the rule that for natural numbers $a, b, c$ we can deduce
$b = c$
from either
$a + b = a + c$
or
$ab = ac$).

After this, he defines $a > b$ and $b < a$ as the case that there is a (natural) number $u$ such that $a = b + u$, and gives the properties

- Exactly one of $a < b$, $a = b$, and $a > b$ is true
- If $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$
- If $a < b$ then $a + c < b + c$
- If $a < b$ then $ac < bc$.

Finally, he defines $a - b$ as the unique solution $u$ of the equation $a = b + u$.

In this context, he proceeds to the following definition of the integers.

> By incorporating the symbols $-a$ (negative integers) and $0$ (zero), the sequence of positive integers can be extended to the domain of *whole numbers* (all *integers*). In order to explain the symbols $+$, $\cdot$, $<$ in this domain more conveniently, it is a matter of expediency to represent the whole numbers by pairs of natural numbers $(a, b)$, namely,
>
> - the natural number $a$ by $(a + b, b)$
> - the zero by $(b, b)$
> - the negative integer $-a$ by $(b, a + b)$,
>
> where $b$ is an arbitrary natural number in each case.

> Every number may be represented by several symbols $(a, b)$; but each symbol $(a, b)$ defines one, and only one, whole number, namely,
>
> - the natural number $a - b$ if $a > b$
> - the number $0$ if $a = b$
> - the negative integer $-(b-a)$ if $a < b$.

> Now we define
>
> - $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d) $
> - $(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (ac + bd, ad + bc) $
> - $(a, b) < (c, d)$ or $(c, d) > (a, b)$, if $a + d < b + c$,
>
> and we verify easily: *first*, that the definitions are independent of the choice of left-hand symbols, provided only that the numbers represented by these symbols remain the same$\ldots$

My difficulty is in to carrying out this first verification, which I understand to be verifying that these definitions are well-defined.

I am familiar, in a shallow way, with the equivalence-class definition in which

$$ (a, b) \sim (c, d) :\iff a + d = b + c, $$

and I've found online (e.g. [here](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Efreiwald/310integers.pdf)) how to carry through the well-definedness proof with this approach.

Working with Van der Waerden's definition, however, I'm running into case analyses that I can't resolve, because the notion of equality between two integers $(a,b)$ and $(c, d)$ entails three cases.

My question then is twofold: How do we show that addition (and multiplication, and the less-than sign) is well-defined from this definition, and is there a way to avoid a complex case analysis and give an elegant demonstration of the same?

Comment: The part in the middle of your three quotes is not a definition. It is a statement of how you should think intuitively about these pairs $(a,b)$, but as it relies on the as-yet undefined concepts of "$0$" and "negative integers", it fails to be a definition. The real definition is effectively the one you wrote down as an equivalence relation, though expressed as $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if and only if $a+d = b+c$. Here "$(a,b)$" is to be considered as an abstract "symbol", not as an ordered pair, and the statement is defining what "$=$" means between two of these symbols. (cont.)

Comment: I do not know exactly how Van der Waerden explicitly defines this equality, but however it is done, it is equivalent to $(a,b) = (c,d) \iff a+d = b+c$. You should show that first. Then you use this relation to prove the results you are after. (A similar practise of defining "$=$' is commonly used for surreal numbers, though there the reason is that the surreals are too large to be a set. So the normal means of defining equivalence relations is not possible.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I think my question is not being understood properly. My difficulty lies in the fact that Van der Waerden does not define it in the manner of the relation $(a, b) = (c, d) \iff a + d = b + c$. I have included his entire definition, together with the context, to make it more understandable. Are you able to show me how, from the definition given above, one might derive that $(a, b) = (c, d) \iff a + d = b + c$? Because that would deal with my difficulty.

Comment: I should also clarify that the three quotes are consecutive in the book and are the entire definition given of integers.

Comment: I should have read the first quote more carefully. Between the two they do represent a definition of integers (sort of: he is doing something abstract - rather than defining specific objects to be integers, they are abstract "symbols" which he is then connecting to pairs of natural numbers). However, the rest of my comment still pertains. You should use the statements to show that two pairs $(a, b)$ and $(c,d)$ represent the same integer if and only if $a + d = b+c$. If you do that, you will find the elegant demonstrations you are after.

Comment: I did try to derive this (i.e. that $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ represent the same integer iff $a + d = b + c$) before asking the question, and was unable. Are you able to help with this? (I began by focusing on the "easy" case where $a > b$ and $c >d$, and this leads to the formula $a - b = c - d$, but it's unclear how to move from here to $a + d = b + c$ because nothing like "add $b$ and $c$ to both sides" has been defined. The closest is the definition of "$-$" (above) which establishes that the equations $a = b + u$ and $c = d + u$ are solved by $u = a - b = c - d$.)

Comment: " nothing like 'add b and c to both sides' has been defined". Not so. $a,b,c,d$ are *natural numbers*, Per your second paragraph, you have seen the development of them, their operations, and the properties of those operations. One of those properties is that $+$ is well-defined: if $u = v$, then $u+t = v + t$. The operation of addition does not change values just because the same two numbers being added were represented in a different fashion.

Comment: Thank you for this remark about the well-definedness of the addition on the natural numbers. I hadn't caught it, but with it I'm able to show that
$$ (a, b) \text{ and } (c, d) \text{ represent the same number } \iff a + d = b + c, $$
which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help [Paul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/258282/paul-sinclair)'s comments above, I've come up with the following argument to show that Van der Waerden's definition of "representing" a given whole number is equivalent to the usual form.

Let $a, b, c, d$ be natural numbers. If $(a, b) = (c, d)$ (i.e. if they "represent" the same whole number) the mutual exclusiveness of the cases in the definition (natural number, $0$, and negative integer) implies that
$a > b \iff c > d$, $a = b \iff c = d$ and $a < b \iff c < d$.
Since exactly one of these is true (according to the properties listed above for natural numbers) we can consider them in turn.

1. If $a > b$ then $c > d$, and $(a, b) = (c, d)$ means $a - b = c - d$, according to the natural number case of whole number representation. Now
   $$ (a - b) + b = (a - b) + b = a, $$
   by virtue of the well-definednes of addition of natural numbers (and commutativity of addition and the definition of $a - b$. Similarly,
   $ (c - d) + d = d $,
   so that (again because addition is well-defined) adding $b$ and $d$ to both sides of the equation $a - b = c - d$ gives us
   $$ a + d = b + c $$
   (after we rearrange using commutativity).
2. If $a < b$ then $c < d$ and we begin with $b - a = d - c$ and an identical argument will prove $d + a = c + b$, which is the same equation (commutativity of addition).
3. Finally, if $a = b$ then $c = d$ and obviously $d = c$, so the well-definedness of addition (adding the first and last equation here) gives us $a + d = b + c$ again.

For the converse we assume (for natural numbers $a, b, c, d$) that we have
$$ a + d = b + c. $$

If $a > b$ then $a - b$ exists and we can add it to both sides of the above to obtain

$$ a + d + (a - b) = b + c + (a - b) = (a - b) + b + c = a + c, $$

in which the second equality is from commutativity and the last is the definition of $a - b$. But now from the deductive rule in the first paragraph of my question we can conclude that

$$ c = d + (a - b), $$

establishing that $c > d$ and (from the definition and uniqueness of $c - d$) that $c - d = a - b$, so that clearly $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ are the same natural number.

If $a < b$, a virtually identical argument to the above will establish

$$ d = c + (b - a), $$

so that $c < d$ also and $b - a = d - c$, so that $(a, b) = (c, d)$ is a negative integer.

Finally, if $a = b$, we have

$$ a + d = a + c, $$

so that $c = d$, and both $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ must represent $0$.

PS. Although the above argument seems sound to me, I can't help but be unsatisfied with it, because it strikes me as though Van der Waerden could've given $a + d = b + c$ as the criterion of equality rather than the case-based rules he provides if all he wanted was for the reader to proceed from the single equation. Is there an argument that moves directly from his definitions to a proof of the well-definedness of the operations?